# What do Schengen border agents see on their computers when they scan the passport?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, schengen, schengen-visas, borders, iceland

So upon landing in Iceland (KEF) from Canada, what would the border agent there see on their screen when I hand over my passport to them?

1. Do they see where I came from and on which flight?
2. Do they see where I am headed and on what flight? Does this change if I book a separate ticket for domestic travel within schengen zone (different PNR than the one I arrived into Iceland from Canada) vs continuing in the same PNR from Canada- Iceland- Any other schengen state?
3. Any other details?

If it helps I am travelling on a schengen short stay tourist visa with ME on my Indian passport and permanent residency of Canada.

Comment: Some information *may* also depend on the country and the airport.

Comment: You've asked several questions on this topic and the gist is that you're worried the border control officers will uncover your *real* plans. I suggest you assume that they will.

Comment: @littleadv Am assuming they will and the intention is not to hide anything from them or to lie to them. But this is just out of curiosity, so I hope nobody assumes that I am going to lie.

Comment: If you're not going to hide anything from them, what does it matter what they already knows? You might get penalised for hiding stuff from them, but not for telling them stuff they already know.

Comment: It can well be assumed that they can easily obtain the information which flight you came with - because they need to know who has to fly you back for free in case they decide your visa is invalid. I am however unsure whether that information is *immediately* available to them on-screen - after all that's why passengers are usually urged to fill-in some paperwork a short time before landing

Comment: The passport itself is read-only to the best of my knowledge, so immediately they would only get the passport number and stuff -- but then they would obviously run it through all their databases like lost and stolen passports, SIS, whatnot and that's where I no longer know the answer.